# Spread slice as list of args

Tags: go

I have this func:

```
func Middleware(adapters ...interface{}) http.HandlerFunc {
    // ...
}
```

and I am trying to call it via:

```
middleware := []mw.Adapter{mw.Error(),mw.Auth("x-huru-api-token")}
router.HandleFunc("/person_data_field", 
mw.Middleware(middleware...,h.makeGetMany(v))).Methods("GET")
```

this doesn't compile though, I get:

[image]

In any case, I need to spread the slice so that it is sent as multiple arguments not just one arg...

With JS, it just looks like this:

```
const v = [1,2,3];

const f = function(...values){
    console.log(values);  // [1,2,3,4]
};

f(...v,4);
```

Comment: IOW, if I don't use the spread operator, it will compile, but that is actually incorrect, I need to spread the slice somehow

Comment: You can pass variadic arguments individually or as a single slice.  You cannot mix and match.

Comment: @ThunderCat I updated the OP to make it clearer, with a JS example, there should be a way to do this, but if not, damn that is lame

Comment: @ThunderCat if it's not possible, can you show an example of how to flat the arguments list in the `Middleware` function? Basically, if an arg is a slice, flatten it into it's elements, etc.

Comment: `[]T` for any `T` other than `interface{}` is not assignable to `[]interface{}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass variadic arguments individually or as a single slice. You cannot mix and match. The slice element type must match the variadic argument type.

To fix the problem, put all of the variadic arguments in a slice of `[]interface{}`:

```
middleware := []interface{}{mw.Error(),mw.Auth("x-huru-api-token"), h.makeGetMany(v)}
router.HandleFunc("/person_data_field", mw.Middleware(middleware...)).Methods("GET")
```

Use [slice tricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks) if you cannot build the slice directly as shown in the previous snippet.

```
middleware := []mw.Adapter{mw.Error(),mw.Auth("x-huru-api-token")}
router.HandleFunc("/person_data_field", mw.Middleware(
    append(append([]interface{}{}, middleware...), h.makeGetMany(v)))).Methods("GET")
```

Comment: this will compile but it's not want I want/need to do. it's a language limitation, unfortunately. I think the work around is to flatten the arguments in the mw.Middleware func..